# Can I call TranslateMessage inside the message callback?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, message-queue

I don't have the canonical message loop running, so is there a way I can call TranslateMessage (or its equivalent) inside my message proc handler?

Basically I need `WM_CHAR` messages and unless I can call TranslateMessage I'm not going to get those. Currently I have the message proc setup, but no message loop.

```
// Static window function called by Windows for message processing. Implementation 
// delegates message processing to MemberWndProc.
LRESULT CALLBACK FxPlayerTiny::WindowsMsgStatic(HWND hwnd, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

      msg = PeekMessage(&msg, HWnd, WM_KEYFIRST, WM_KEYLAST, PM_NOREMOVE);

      if (msg type is key down){

            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            //DispatchMessage(&msg); -- needed?

      }
      else process msg normally
}
```

My message proc handler is the first point of entry of messages, being setup in the following manner:

```
WNDCLASSEX  wc;
wc.lpfnWndProc    = WindowsMsgStatic;
....
RegisterClassEx(&wc);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point, in order to get a queued message, you must call a function like `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage`. Those functions yield `MSG` objects and it is those `MSG` objects that you must pass to `TranslateMessage` and `DispatchMessage`.

In the code in the original version of the question, you are trying to call `TranslateMessage` and `DispatchMessage` too late. You call them inside your window proc. You should call them at the point where you first receive the `MSG` object. In other words, call `TranslateMessage` and `DispatchMessage` straight after the call to `PeekMessage` or `GetMessage`.

Comment: Your code edit makes my answer now look silly. I don't really want to have to re-write it over and over. Regarding `WM_CHAR`, they are posted to the window by `TranslateMessage`. The problem with your question(s) is that you are presenting only a tiny window on the problem. So we can address that tiny window, but then you discover that the underlying problem has not been fully addressed. And so you then open the window wider and change our view. You should tell us everything!

Comment: Thats all I have! I don't have anymore code dealing with the message loop to show!

Comment: But there's no big picture for us to see. I can say that it cannot be right that you are pumping the queue in a window proc.

Comment: Well, what's going on is that I started with this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690953/what-exactly-is-going-on-in-this-win32-messaging-loop#15691124 (code in the question) ... and I am not using the message loop at all because I cannot afford to have it blocking. And I don't want to go multi threaded either. I want to keep it in one thread and still have messages work. Most everything is fine except for keyboard messages for which I need the char codes. Thats the whole big picture, sorry for any confusion.

Comment: And I'm not pumping the queue in the proc, currently I have a regular messaging proc which simply processing messages. Trouble is that keycodes are coming up all wierd because I'm not using TranslateMessage. All I have is this static message handler.

Comment: You **must** be calling `PeekMessage` or `GetMessage` somewhere, otherwise your window will never receive any messages at all and your program will appear to lock up. Wherever you're calling those functions is where you must also call `TranslateMessage`.

Comment: In the code in the current version of this question, I can see you pumping the queue in the window proc. I can't understand why you can't use a blocking message queue. 99.999% of apps do that successfully. What is stopping you?

Comment: Just for completeness, `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` is a viable alternative to `GetMessage` and `PeekMessage`.