# What exactly is going on in this Win32 messaging loop?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, messaging

What exactly is going on inside this Win32 messaging loop? I understand that `TranslateMessage` is converting keycodes to UTF char codes and sending the `WM_CHAR` event, but what is the call to `PeekMessage` doing exactly? Is it filtering out a certain type of message and only translating those?

```
// Application / Player message loop.
MSG msg;
ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(msg));

while(msg.message != WM_QUIT)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

   // work happens here...
}
```

Comment: PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE) msg holds the message. NULL here denotes that it takes window messages and thread messages. OU and OU means that it takes all available messages and does not do filtering. PM_REMOVE means that it removes the message after processing. And it returns true, if there is a message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally the message loop will use `GetMessage` instead of `PeekMessage`. The difference is that `PeekMessage` returns immediately. Returning either `TRUE` if a message was removed, or `FALSE` if no message was fetched. On the other hand if the queue is empty, `GetMessage` blocks until a message arrives.

The point is the comment stating *work happens here*. Presumably the author had some reason why the normal blocking message loop would not suffice. The down side of the non-blocking message loop code in the question is that it is a busy loop. It will not idle and so it will fully consume the CPU, unless there is a call to `Sleep()` or similar that you have excised.

In a comment you say that you actually want to pull off keyboard messages only, and just messages for a specific window. You need to call `PeekMessage` like this:

```
PeekMessage(&msg, hwnd, WM_KEYFIRST, WM_KEYLAST, PM_REMOVE)
```

Answer (score 2):

All it is is a nonblocking way to get messages.  It checks to see if there is a message, and if there is, it takes it out of the queue and puts it in &msg.

Check [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The second parameter says which window to look in.  In this case, it's "all windows in the thread."

The third and fourth parameter do let you specify whether you want keyboard or mouse events, but currently is set to "all".

Comment: How can I change it so it only works for the current window, and only gets keyboard events?

Comment: Please don't ask that in a comment. That question should be asked in a question. It's easy to answer too.

Comment: `PeekMessage(&msg, HWnd, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE)` to filter messages for this window ....

Comment: You need the HWND for the window you want to catch events on.  Just pass that as the second parameter.  As for keyboard only, in parameters 3 and 4, pass WM_KEYFIRST and WM_KEYLAST respectively.

Comment: @Geotarget You actually want `PeekMessage(&msg, HWnd, WM_KEYFIRST, WM_KEYLAST, PM_REMOVE)`

Comment: Thanks very much! Can you help with my actual issue also? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690920/can-i-call-translatemessage-inside-the-message-callback/15691228#15691228